# If form validation failed then redirect back with input using custom request class (laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5.8

The problem is i want to return back with the inputs when the validation is fails. Here I'm using a custom request class to validate user input.

> **Now my question is where i place this piece of code on *Controller* Or in *Request class*. 
>
>   or is there another way to do it?**

Here is the code i want to use:
`return redirect()->back()->withInput();`

***Here is the Controller:***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\Admin\counter\CreateCounterRequest;
use App\Models\Admin\Counter;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CounterController extends Controller
{
    public function store(CreateCounterRequest $request)
    {
        Counter::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'ion_icon' => $request->ion_icon,
            'counter_value' => $request->counter_value,
        ]);
        session()->flash('success', 'Counters created successfully.');
        return redirect(route('counter.index'));
    }
}
```

***Here is the Request Class:***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin\counter;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateCounterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'ion_icon' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'counter_value' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use `{{old('field_name')}}` in value of your fields in blade, like this `<input type="text" name="field_name" value="{{old('field_name')}}">`.

Comment: @Reza Sh thanks for your help. but if i want to use create & update page with same view then how can i implement this? because i already use this view for update .   `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ion-icon"
                                       placeholder="ion-ios-people" name="ion_icon"
                                       value="{{ isset($counter) ? $counter->ion_icon : '' }}">`

Answer (score 4):

you can use a method from **FormRequest** class, that is **failedValidation()** method.

and example code is like this:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

you must add a argument from **Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator** class to your method **failedValidation** and add **Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse** class for get redirect method.

add **Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException** class, if not your method cant be read.

Answer (score 1):

please check this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'ion_icon' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'counter_value' => 'required',
        ]);
    }
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('your_route')->withInput(['title' => $request->title, 'icon_icon' => $request->icon_icon,'counter_value' => $request->couter_value,'phone_number'=>$request->phone_number])->withErrors($validator, 'your_desire_name');
        }
        Counter::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'ion_icon' => $request->ion_icon,
            'counter_value' => $request->counter_value,
        ]);
        session()->flash('success', 'Counters created successfully.');
        return redirect(route('counter.index'));
    }
```

Want In Your Blade File Show this error message

```
<div >

                                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control"
                                       value="{{old('title')}}" required>


                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->your_desire_name->has('title'))


                                <span class="messages"><p
                                        class="text-danger error">{{ $errors->your_desire_name->first('title') }}</p></span>



                            @endif
```